# Python input_schema gives 'list index out of range' when using classes

Tags: python, pandas, type-inference

I'm using the [inference-schema](https://pypi.org/project/inference-schema/) package in order to convert data from an API call to a correctly formatted Pandas dataframe.

This worked great until i tried to put the Run method inside a class, then it starts throwing 'list index out of range' errors.

See code example below:

```
from numpy.core.numeric import NaN
import pandas as pd
from inference_schema.schema_decorators import input_schema
from inference_schema.parameter_types.pandas_parameter_type import PandasParameterType

def get_schema():
    return pd.DataFrame({"Test": [ 0.0, NaN]})

@input_schema('df', PandasParameterType(get_schema()))
def Run(df):
    return df['Test']*2

class Score:
    @input_schema('df', PandasParameterType(get_schema()))
    def Run(self, df):
        return df['Test']*2

score = Score()

df = [{"Test": 21.0}]

result = Run(df) # This Run method without a class works fine
print(result)

result = score.Run(df) # Identical Run method inside a Class gives error 'list index out of range'
print(result)
```

How can I achieve this, either with inference-schema or other suitable python-packages?

Comment: not sure why in the class it fails. But by looking at the source code of the package, it seems to use json dumps and pd.read_json (plus a lot of format/data verification of course). With you example, you could do `import json` then in your class do `def Run(self, df): return pd.read_json(json.dumps(df))['Test']*2`, it works. In your real case, what would be a block (as I assume it would be that easy) to do this?

Comment: Yep, that seems to work in my case. Thank you!